# Why does "foo != 1" behave differently than "not(foo = 1)" in xslt if there's no foo node present?

Tags: xslt

I had a condition in XSLT like this:

```
 <xsl:if test="foo != 1">
     <p>This should be shown if foo doesn't equal one</p>
 </xsl:if>
```

`foo` is a flag here. If `foo` was 1 or 0 it worked fine. But if there was no `foo` element defined the condition returned false as if `foo` was equal to 1.

I've changed it to

```
 <xsl:if test="not(foo = 1)">
     <p>This should be shown if foo doesn't equal one</p>
 </xsl:if>
```

And it began to work as I expected: if there's no `foo`, the condition will be also true.

Can somebody explain why is it so in XSLT. And what is the best way to check that the node doesn't exist as well as that it doesn't have a specific value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement says:

```
if there is a foo element that is not 1
```

for this to be true a foo element has to exist, otherwise this is false even if there is no foo element at all

your second statement says:

```
if there is no foo element that is 1
```

this is the correct way to do what you want, because it is also true if there is no foo element at all

Answer (score 0):

Using the following input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <test>
        <foo>1</foo>
    </test>
    <test>
        <foo>0</foo>
    </test>
    <test>
        <a>xxx</a>
    </test>    
</root>
```

and the following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="//test">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(foo[.!=1])">
                <p>aaa</p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <p>bbb</p>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<p>aaa</p>

<p>bbb</p>

<p>aaa</p>
```

Comment: This is the oppposite of what was asked, since here 'aaa' is what the Op had as 'This should be shown if foo doesn't equal one'

Comment: arrived at that answer because the OP wanted `And what is the best way to check that the node doesn't exist as well as that it doesn't have a specific value?`

Comment: I think he posted the solution to that himself, `not(foo = 1)` does that, without a double negative that is usually hard to grasp...

Comment: well, if you changed `<xsl:when test="not(foo[.!=1])">` to `<xsl:when test="not(foo = 1)">`, the result is `<p>bbb</p>`, `<p>aaa</p>`, and `<p>aaa</p>` respectively.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but, as @TobiasKlevenz wrote, a bit complicated  to my taste because of double negation. Thank you.

Comment: the double negation arose from your requirement `And what is the best way to check that the node doesn't exist as well as that it doesn't have a specific value?`. It doesn't exist **and** it doesn't have a specific value.